# How change node background color of a disabled Tree-Viewer

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a Tree-Viewer in SWT. I select one Node/Row in that and I changed that row's background color let say to green.

Now I'm disabling tree-viewer but now hole Tree-Viewer is disabled and background color is also gone.

I know it is because I'm disabling the viewer. But is there any way so that selected row's background color should same as we set it, after disabling the viewer.

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: @Baz treeViewer.getTree().setEnabled(false);

Comment: Looks like this may be platform dependent, it doesn't seem to happen on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using StyledCellLabelProvider, which you can successfully extend to provide styling of your labels like this: (Please also see a [TextStyle](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/TextStyle.html) class for more formatting options).

```
public class MyStyledLabelProvider extends StyledCellLabelProvider {

private Styler defaultStyler;
public MyStyledLabelProvider () {
        defaultStyler = new Styler() {
            @Override
            public void applyStyles(TextStyle textStyle) {
                textStyle.strikeout = true;
            }
        };
    }

@Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        Object element = cell.getElement();
        StyledString styledString = getStyledString(element);
        cell.setText(styledString.toString());
        cell.setStyleRanges(styledString.getStyleRanges());
        super.update(cell);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private StyledString getStyledString(Object element) {
        return new StyledString("Cell string", defaultStyler);
    }
}
```